# Confused about the API changes

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Since LinkedIn support has moved to StackOverflow... here we go. It might seem like a stupid question though...

The LinkedIn API will move to v2 in the near future, but I am unsure which data will really remain available (without being a LinkedIn Partner).

I have been reading the API v2 documentation. This talks about r_basicprofile (which I have used with v1), but this will be replaced with r_liteprofile. (I quote: "This API will only recognize a new “Lite Profile” permission, which supports a reduced set of member profile fields.")

So, r_liteprofile only has a couple of data fields (first name, last name, maiden name, profile picture). In the future, how am I to get the LinkedIn profile URL from this? And some other information that is not necessarily privacy sensitive?

If I try to get more data through r_liteprofile it doesn't show them, which would be expected behavior according to the r_liteprofile documentation. But how am I supposed to link to people's LinkedIn profile from my application? Doesn't LinkedIn want people to come back to their platform through other websites?

So, in conclusion:
After March 1st, will there still be a way to get the profile URL, and perhaps the headline and industry ID?

The obvious answer is "no you can't". I'm just hoping for a "yes you can".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: it's not possible to maintain the r_basicprofile fields without applying for a LinkedIn partnership, starting March 1st, 2019 (when the transition from the LinkedIn API v1 to v2 will be made).

Answer (score 0):

From the migration docs:

"Looking to maintain access to the Basic Profile fields? Learn more about applying to a LinkedIn Partner Program."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context#what-are-the-main-differences-with-the-new-sign-in-with-linkedin

Comment: Yes, You can get LinkedIn profile URL Now and later also with V2 just apply for partnership program. after approval you can use r_basicprofile

Answer (score 0):

You can get more fields by specifying them in url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))
```

You can find more fields here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. However, the r_liteprofile doesn't allow usage of any more than the ones you stated and the e-mailaddress with r_emailaddress. The problem isn't that I'm not able to request the data, I'm just not receiving the data because of the v2 access limitations. For that, I need r_fullprofile.

Comment: if you want fetch email, you need to make another separated request

Comment: I don't believe you understand the original question... I don't have any problems with getting the e-mail address. I just wanted to know whether I could still get some of the r_basicprofile data fields with the v2 without applying for a partnership. Apparently I can't.